# On the Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates and Skeletons

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Say that $\mathcal{X}$ is a conglomerate if $\mathcal{X} = \{X_i: i \in I\}$, where each $X_i$ and $I$ are classes. The Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates is the statement: Whenever $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are conglomerates and $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is a surjective map, then $f$ has a right inverse.

The "Axiom of Choice for Classes" and the (usual) "Axiom of Choice for Sets"
may be defined in the obvious, analogous way (i.e., "Whenever $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are classes $\ldots$ etc." in the first case, and "Whenever $X$ and $Y$ are sets $\ldots$ etc." in the second).The Axiom of Choice for Classes implies the existence of a global choice function (meaning, a class function which is a choice function for the class of all non-empty sets), and the latter is, in turn, equivalent to the existence of a well-ordering of the universe.

Well, it is well-known that the Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates implies that "Every category has a skeleton" (see, e.g., Adamék/Herrlich/Strecker book). On the other hand, Isbell and Wright have proved in the 60's that the statement "Every category has a skeleton" implies the existence of a well-ordering of the universe.

My question is: considering the following assertions,

"The Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates"

and

"Every category has a skeleton"

are they equivalent statements ? At first glance, my conjecture is that the answer is "Yes", but I didn't find any reference for that.

Added (1): In Freyd/Scedrov book it is shown that the Axiom of Choice for Sets is equivalent to the statement "Every small category has a skeleton". So I also wonder whether there is some ladder of equivalences between forms of the Axiom of Choice and assertions regarding the existence of skeletons for certain categories. I mean, considering statements as

"Every small category has a skeleton",

"Every locally small category has a skeleton", and

"Every category has a skeleton", and maybe other similar statements of this kind,

could we put each one of them in correspondence with some equivalent form of the Axiom of Choice ? The first one is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice for Sets, as I have just commented.

Added (2): After getting some comments it seems that the set-theoretic background should be more specified. The question was posed assuming the usual foundations of category theory - but, of course, this is a very debatable issue. In a first moment, we could think of ZFC + 2 inaccessibles, and then in such environment code the notions of: set, class and conglomerate. However, whether we are in first or second order seems also to have influence on this matter.

I was also told that, indeed, the Axiom of Choice for Classes is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates: the Axiom of Choice for Classes, as stated above, is equivalent to the existence of a well-ordering in any class, and so we could use such well-ordering to define a right inverse.

So, I guess that, indeed, my real question is: how can we define precisely a background (both categorically and set-theoretically) where we could analyze statements as the ones listed at the end of the question,

"Every small category has a skeleton",

"Every locally small category has a skeleton",

"Every category has a skeleton", etc.,

and what forms of the Axiom of Choice would these statements be equivalent to ?

Comment: There's no reason to post the question here, where you posted it on Math.SE just a few hours ago.

Comment: Hi Asaf, several people told me that this question would fit better in MathOverflow. Should I delete it from Math.SE before post it here ? I am sorry if I did something against the rules.

Comment: Yes, you should have asked the moderators to migrate the question, instead of posting a new one. As for what it's worth. I don't necessarily agree that it won't get a good answer on Math.SE, which is why the right thing to do was to let it sit for a few days and see what sort of attention it attracts, then if all else fails post here (or, as one should, request the question to be migrated).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about such possibility of migration. Sorry again, I am not used to this yet. I will let a note at the end of the question at Math.SE about that.

Comment: What you call a conglomerate is also commonly known as a meta-class. But I find talk about them as a little meaningless without more context as to the background assumptions. Are you working in a version of GBC or what? And what kind of functions $f$ do you have? It doesn't really make sense to ask if two statements are equivalent, when the axiomatic framework is unspecified.

Comment: What you call the axiom of choice for conglomerates has certain affinity with what is known as the principle of class choice, stated in the usual language of GBC, namely: if for every set $i$ there is a class $X$ for which $\varphi(i,X)$, then there is a class $X\subset V\times V$ such that for every set $i$ we have $\varphi(i,X_i)$, where $X_i$ is the $i^{th}$ section of $X$. This is strictly stronger than global choice, and is not provable even with Kelley-Morse set theory. We analyze this axiom in some current joint work with Victoria Gitman, Thomas Johnstone and myself.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I will check your paper with Gitman and Johnstone. Regarding your first comment: I guess we have to assume that we are under the usual foundations for category theory - but of course this is a very debatable issue. We could think of ZFC + 2 inacessible cardinals, and then code in such environment the notions of set, class and conglomerate. But the idea is that the equivalences would be placed where the foundations for category theory are.

Comment: Well, if you have ZFC + inaccessibles, and class here refers to subsets of the universe $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is one of the inaccessibles, then your conglomerate choice principle at that level is simply outright provable in your background theory, because it amounts to an instance of AC in your ZFC there.

Comment: Yes Joel, a colleague has just commented that in another post; indeed, what I called "The Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates" seems to be equivalent to "The Axiom of Choice for Classes". Nevertheless, I still would like to be sure that such statement is, indeed, equivalent to "Every category has a skeleton", and also if variations of statements like these (as the one I added at the end of the question) could be put in equivalence with some forms of the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Well, there are various versions of class choice, depending on whether $\varphi$ in my statement is first-order only or second-order, etc., and these are not equivalent to each other. Such differences correspond to asking about the nature of $f$ in your question.  Frankly, I don't find the question meaningful until the axiomatic background is more fully specified. But I think it is possible to do that, and I encourage you to refine your question so that it becomes meaningful.

Comment: OK, I will think of that.

Comment: Dear Samuel, did you already look at a thorough presentation of categories in the framework of Grothendieck universes, such as SGA 4.I.0-1 together with the Bourbaki appendix to SGA 4.I (keeping in mind that SGA uses Bourbaki's set theory as described in his _Théorie des ensembles._)? It seems to me that this might yield a possibility to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Fred, I will try to take a look.